# HTML Auto Resizing banner to fit different screen resolutions?

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a website and implemented a banner. The code is

```
<div id="banner"><div>
    <div id="wrapper" style="width:100%; overflow:hidden;"">
    <div id="container" style="width:800px; margin-right:auto;"">
    <A HREF="http://www.nalashirts.com"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/jdoascd.png"
        alt="N.A.L.A. Apparel"
    />
</div></div>
```

I want the image to re-size automatically to fit the resolution of the users browser. How would I go about that?

Comment: have a look at css responsive design.

Comment: @DanielA.White Will take a look right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I added a "width: 100%" to the "" and ".container".

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/boaf07t2/2/)

Here is the new code.

```
<div id="banner">
    <div id="wrapper" style="width:100%; overflow:hidden;">
        <div id="container" style="width:100%; margin-right:auto;">
                <A HREF="http://www.nalashirts.com"><img style="width: 100%;" src="http://i.imgur.com/jdoascd.png" alt="N.A.L.A. Apparel"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This can be fixed without inline styles. Here is the new HTML:

```
<div id="banner">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="container">
                <a href="http://www.nalashirts.com"><img class="banner-img" src="http://i.imgur.com/jdoascd.png" alt="N.A.L.A. Apparel"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the corresponding CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.banner-img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

*Note: We use `banner-img` as the class name to not overwrite the default `img` tag styles.*

Comment: Oh, that was a very fast fix. Thanks! But I am now curious on how I can implement the CSS code for future references :D

Comment: Thank you! Yea, trying to tool with this now. :]

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this:

```
img{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
max-height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, 
 <div id="wrapper" style="width:100%; height:100%; max-height: 300px; overflow:hidden;"">

Didn't work out as well

Comment: @ImranChowdhry:- Can you share a jsfiddle? BTW this is the change in CSS

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/boaf07t2/ @R.T.

Comment: @ImranChowdhry:- Are you looking for this:- http://jsfiddle.net/boaf07t2/1/

Comment: Yes!! Exactly that! Now would I try to add this code in another file or would I be able to somehow manage to add it in one file? Sorry, really new to HTML/CSS @R.T.

Comment: @ImranChowdhry:- You have to create a new CSS file and add the code there. BTW dont forget to accept this as answer if that helped you. :)

Comment: Thank you sir :D , will do. There's 2 answers, i can't mark both as correct :x

Comment: @ImranChowdhry:- Also do remember that adding the changes in the CSS file is a good practice. The other solution although worked for you but it is not a recommended way

Comment: Done! :D Thanks, didn't have the up-votes until now! Very appreciative of the help here at Stack Overflow!